# How to get Bootstrap menu to close upon click when using NavLinks in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router, navbar

I have a Bootstrap 4 Navbar in my React application using React Router, and so instead of `<a>` elements, I have `<NavLink>` elements.

The following code works well, except for when one is in mobile view and has the menu open, while clicking on one of the menu items switches the page, it doesn't close the menu.

**How can I get the mobile-view menu to close upon click?**

I have found some answers which involve adding a `data-toggle="collapse"` to the `<a>` elements, but this doesn't work on `<NavLink>` elements.

[image]

```
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="#"><NavLink className="nav-link" exact to="/"><span className="appTitle">Onespace</span></NavLink></a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/languages">Languages</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/news">News</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/runs">Runs</NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Did you solve this in the end? I am facing the same problem. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

I think I had the same problem. For me I solved it with a workaround by using an onClick event to add / remove the corresponding classes for the button (hamburger) and the dropdown menu.

The function:

```
  handleCollapse = () => {
    console.log("handleCollapse");
    var nav = document.getElementById("navbarNav");
    var btn = document.getElementById("navbarBtn");
    nav.classList.remove("show");
    btn.classList.add("collapsed");
  };
```

The NavBar (with reduced content):

```
render() {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top">
      <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/index">
        <img src="/x.png" className="d-inline-block align-top" loading="lazy"></img>
        PPlan
      </Link>
      <button
        className="navbar-toggler" id="navbarBtn" type="button" 
        data-target="#navbarNav" data-toggle="collapse" 
        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <NavLink to={/1} className="nav-item nav-link" onClick={this.handleCollapse}>
            User
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/2" className="nav-item nav-link" onClick={this.handleCollapse}>
            PrjPlan
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```